# Select From Table A but Exclude where a match exists in table B

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 Tables, Subscribers & Send log. I need to select all subscribers but exclude records that match my criteria in the Sendlog table.

The Criteria is that they  are a "PowerUser", The SubscribePreference = 1 and that they have never recieved a "GoPro" email

I have a SQL fiddle here to represent it but cannot figure out the query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e1a7/6

In this Sample I would like to return Dave, Ed & Frank because the have never recieved a "GoPro" email

Can someone help me out here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.EmailAddress
   , 'GoPro' AS CampaignName
  , sl.SendDate
FROM Subscribers s 
LEFT JOIN SendLog sl 
  ON s.EmailAddress = sl.EmailAddress
  AND CampaignName = 'GoPro'
WHERE s.Entitlement = 'PowerUser' 
AND s.SubscribePreference = 1
AND sl.EmailAddress IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e1a7/17

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Subscribers.EmailAddress
FROM   Subscribers
LEFT OUTER JOIN SendLog
       ON Subscribers.EmailAddress = SendLog.EmailAddress
       AND SendLog.CampaignName = 'GoPro'
WHERE  SendLog.EmailAddress IS NULL
       AND Subscribers.SubscribePreference = 1
       And Subscribers.Entitlement = 'PowerUser'
```

For performance reasons, I suggest adding an ID column as Primary Key to the Subscribers table, then create a Foreign Key called SubscriberID in the SendLog table and join them on that. The query above will work but it would be faster with integers and appropriate keys.